# How to print out all the elements in a list using Java string.format?

Tags: java

In this question, I am trying to printout all the elements in an arraylist and combine it with a sentence, but i can only print one element in the list, it is either the first index or the last index. But the ideal result expected should be for example, list A = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, expect result: "The list contains: a, b, c, d".

Below is what i have got so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("a");
    strings.add("b");
    strings.add("c");
    String result = "hello";
    for (String s : strings) {
        result = String.format("This list contains: %s", s);
    }
    System.out.println(result); //Expected: "This list contains: a, b, c." But: "This list contains: c".
}
```

How should i go about with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.join` instead of `format`

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("a");
strings.add("b");
strings.add("c");
System.out.println("This list contains: " + String.join(", ", strings));
```

Comment: Why not both? `String.format("This list contains: %s", String.join(", ", strings))`